# Using docker without root rights but restricted sudo

Tags: root, docker

I just started a new job and directly got problems with the guys operating our server farms (company is quite big). I was used to use docker and would like to keep that going with the products I am designing.

As a requirement, I told that guys I need the Docker daemon to run as root user. The server guys just told me, that they won't support our machines if we run 3rd party sotfware as a root user. There's no argumentation about that. Period.

But, they told me, if we could use sudo and restrict the sudo rights to the absolute minimum required, this would be a solution.

is there something known how I could handle that or circumvent that dogmatic "I need root" rule?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The Docker daemon is required to be running as root. Once a piece of software is running as root, it has all root permissions. Something like `sudo dockerdaemon` still gives Docker all those rights. This is also exactly why most people restrict `sudo` from running interactive shells or software like `vim` which can run arbitrary external commands. Root access is root access.